# Calling Power shell scripts from C# remotely using Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, powershell, botframework

When i try to run the code I always get error in 
`runspace.open()`

This is the following code:

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectioninfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
connectioninfo.ComputerName = "pnwvsble05";
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectioninfo);
runspace.Open();
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
  ps.Runspace = runspace;
  Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline("Get-Service");
  var results = pipeline.Invoke();
}
```

And the following are the errors:

```
InitialSessionState = '((System.Management.Automation.RemoteRunspace)runspace).InitialSessionState' threw an exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSNotImplementedException' `

JobManager = '((System.Management.Automation.RemoteRunspace)ps.Runspace).JobManager' threw an exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSNotImplementedException'

RunspaceConfiguration = '((System.Management.Automation.RemoteRunspace)ps.Runspace).RunspaceConfiguration' threw an exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSNotImplementedException'
```

Comment: Have you tried to move the runspace.Open() into the using context already?

Comment: its still the same

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/907ddf9c-97fc-4226-b899-6d5c49d552b9/systemmanagementautomationpsnotimplementedexception?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: dint help much....